# I want to make a procedural spiral texture (where I can control centre size)

Tags: modeling, shaders, procedural

The image below has the type of pattern I want.

[image: Bakugan Launcher (Masquerade version)]

I don't want to just put a circle in the center, that will chop of the swirl lines.
I want to make sure the swirl lines end, while still being able to resize the center.

[image: Example of wrong swril]

My experiment with swirl lines, notice how the lines do not properly end.

Here is a good video I found:
https://youtu.be/kr22nm2Vvyc